# JGroups properties inheritance

Tags: jgroups

There is a phrase in JGroups [documentation](http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html/protlist.html#Transport):

> TP is the base class for all transports, e.g. UDP and TCP. All of the properties defined here are inherited by the subclasses.

What do they mean by the word "subclasses"? More specifically, if I set `bind_addr` property in the TCP transport and don't set it in MPING and FD_SOCK protocols, will it be inherited from the TCP transport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, MPING, FD_SOCK, STATE_SOCK get the event and set their bind_addr property accordingly